Event loop blocking in NodeJS
stack overflow community.
I have an app that interacts with Docker using dockerode library in NodeJS. I'm generating services using it and everytime new service is being started, it builds unique image for it first (it has custom properties exactly for the service). This is controlled by http requests in express and I invoke the builds in async blocks. My question is, is there a possibility that the image builds (they take long, like 5 seconds each), can block event loop in the NodeJS app and cause some serious freezes or is it completely fine? I even implemented worker threads but I'm still not sure how exactly it works under the hood.
Library im using for building the images: Dockerode
Thank you!
I expect it to run smoothly, without the requests and event loop being blocked. This all is allright in testing phase, but I have concerns about how it could work in production, if it can freeze and we would need to choose another language and rebuild the system.
Worker code
import {workerData, parentPort} from "worker_threads";
import fs from "fs";
import {initDockerClient} from "../client";

const appConfig = workerData['appConfig'] as any;
const archive = workerData['archive'] as string;
const tag = workerData['imageTag'] as string;
const env = workerData['env'] as any;
const debug = workerData['debug'] as boolean;

const client = initDockerClient(appConfig);
const logs = [];

if (debug) {
    console.log("Running image build inside worker.");
}

client.buildImage(archive, { t: tag, buildargs: env }).then(stream => {
    logs.push('--------- Begin Build Log ---------');
    client.modem.followProgress(stream, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            res.forEach(r => {
                if (r.errorDetail) {
                    console.error(new Error(r.errorDetail));
                } else {
                    const msg = r.stream?.trim();
                    //ctx.logger.info(msg);
                    logs.push(msg);
                }
            });
            logs.push('--------- End Of Build Log ---------\n');
            fs.unlinkSync(archive);
            parentPort.postMessage(logs);
            parentPort.postMessage(tag);
        }
    });
});

if (debug) {
    console.log("End of worker.");
}

Sample code where I invoke the worker
import DockerClient from "dockerode";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import tar from "tar";
import ignore from "../../ignore";
import {currentContext as ctx} from "../../../app";
import {Worker} from "worker_threads";

function logService(id: string, str: any) {
    const log_path = process.cwd() + '/service_logs/' + id + '.log';
    fs.appendFileSync(log_path, (str ?? '').toString() + '\n');
}

function prepareImage({ client, arDir, buildDir, volumeId, env }: PrepareImageOptions, cb: (imageTag: string) => void) {
    const archive = arDir + '/' + path.basename(buildDir) + '-' + volumeId + '.tar';
    const imageTag = volumeId + ':latest';
    //
    const msgHandler = (msg: any) => {
        if (Array.isArray(msg)) {
            msg.forEach(m => logService(volumeId, m));
        } else {
            cb(msg);
        }
    }

    // Build image
    const w = new Worker(__dirname + path.sep + 'build.worker.js', {
        workerData: {
            archive,
            imageTag,
            env,
            appConfig: ctx.appConfig,
            debug: ctx.debug
        }
    });
    w.on('message', msgHandler);
}

Sample code where I invoke the prepareImage function
export default function (self: ServiceEngine, client: DockerClient): ServiceEngine['build'] {
    const arDir = process.cwd() + '/archives';
    if (!fs.existsSync(arDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(arDir);
    }
    return (buildDir, volumeId, options, meta, cb, onclose) => {
        const id = volumeId;

        prepareImage({client, arDir, buildDir, volumeId, env}, (imageTag) => {
            srvLog.info('Image built in ' + imageBuildClock.durFromCreation() + 'ms');

            (async () => {
                let container: DockerClient.Container;
                // Whether, or not we're creating a brand-new service
                let creating = true;
                try {
                    container = await prepareContainer(client, imageTag, buildDir, volumeId, options);
                    await container.start();
                    srvLog.info('Watching changes');
                    // Watcher
                    setTimeout(async () => {
                        const attachOptions = { stream: true, stdout: true, hijack: true };
                        const rws = await client.getContainer(container.id).attach(attachOptions);
                        rws.on('data', (data) => {
                            logService(volumeId, data);
                        }); // no-op, keepalive
                        rws.on('end', async () => {
                            if (getActionType(container.id) != 'stop') {
                                ctx.logger.info('Container ' + container.id + ' stopped from the inside.');
                                await onclose();
                            } else {
                                ctx.logger.info('Container ' + container.id + ' stopped by NSM.');
                            }
                        });
                        (self as DockerServiceEngine).rws[container.id] = rws;
                    }, 500);
                } catch (e) {
                    if (!container) {
                        await client.getImage(imageTag).remove({ force: true });
                    }
                    await cb(undefined, e);
                    return;
                }
                await cb(container.id, undefined);
            })();
        });
    }
}

And code where I invoke the build function
export async function resumeService(id: string) {

    new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        //
        const buildHandler = async (containerId?: string, err?: any) => {
            const saved = await db.saveSession({ serviceId: id, nodeId, containerId });
            // Save new session info
            if (saved) {
                resolve(true);
                return;
            } else {
                resolve(false);
                return;
            }
        }

        // This is the build function above
        engine.build(
            noTAlternateSett ? undefined : buildDir(template),
            id,
            {
                ram: options.ram ?? defaults.ram as number,
                cpu: options.cpu ?? defaults.cpu as number,
                disk: options.disk ?? defaults.disk as number,
                env: env ?? defaults.env as {[key: string]: string},
                port: perma_.port,
                ports: options.ports ?? [],
                network,
            },
            meta,
            buildHandler,
            async () => {
                await stopService(id);
            }
        );
    })
        .then((success) => {
            // success
        })
        .finally(() => {
            // finally
        });
    return true;
}


Have you tried to have it create multiple images at the same time to test this behaviour? I would recommend to test this on a local system with 10, 50 or 100 images and see how it scales up. You can use the Performance API to track how the performance of your solution scales and if any thread is blocking another: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance
